# Can you generate dynamic LESS parameters from a mixin?

Tags: parameters, less, less-mixins

I'm trying to generate a dynamic colour palette for use several sites that have different numbers of brand colours from the same range. I've got a mixin that creates the color range I need like so:

```
.generate-colors(6); // create six evenly spaced colors

.generate-colors(@n, @i: 1) when (@i =< @n) {
    @range: 160;
    @gap: @range / @n;

    // output the background color rule
    .bgcol-@{i} {
        background-color: hsv(160 + ((@i - 1) * @gap), 30%, 75%);
    }
    // output text colour rule
    .col-@{i} {
        color: hsv(160 + ((@i - 1) * @gap), 30%, 75%);
    }
   .generate-colors(@n, (@i + 1));
 }
```

The problem I have is It'd be useful to have this generate LESS parameters so I could re-use those colours for things like borders etc.

If I wasn't using mixins I'd just do:

```
@col-1: red;
@col-2: green; //etc
```

But I'd love to have the mixin generate that for me. I've tried things like this in the mixin:

```
~"@col-{n}": @c;
```

Without any luck - is this even possible, or am I going too far? Really appreciate any help - even if it's a "not possible".

Comment: No, you can't define variables like this. For your use-case the easiest approach would be using something like [functions plugin](http://lesscss.org/usage/#plugins-list-of-less-plugins), so that you'll write a corresponding function and instead of `@col-1` simply use `col(1)` etc. (there're other methods, but those will be much more verbose and cluttering in use).